# Expected Value of Density with Overlap

Tags: combinatorics

Given $x$ items which are randomly distributed to $n$ buckets with uniform distribution. What is the expected value of occupied buckets (one or more items)?

Comment: What is the probability that a given bucket is empty?

Comment: @A.S. The probability that a given bucket is empty is $((n-1)/n)^x$.

Comment: Then what is expected number of empty buckets? Of non-empty buckets?

Comment: @A.S. The expected number of empty buckets is $n ((n-1)/n)^x$. The inverse is clear. So the next step I'm after is: Given a fixed ratio $r = x/n$, what is the expected value for $n \rightarrow \infty$? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Think of one of the definitions of $e^x$.